# Picking up opportunity card on exiting career path

Tags: careers

I recently bought a board game called Careers for a themed party. It looks a lot of fun, I am just reading the rules but cannot work out something.

On exiting a career path you are allowed to take a number of experience cards up to 3, based on the number of times you have been through the career that bit is quite clear. What it doesn't explain is that the same square you return to the main board is usually an opportunity square, which would allow you take a card that would move to another career almost immediately. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would, if you actually landed on the **Opportunity Knocks** square, which only happens 1/6 of the time. When exiting the career path, you continue moving clockwise the full number of spaces that you rolled. Additionally, you need to meet one of the requirements of the new career to enter the career path that the Opportunity card sent you to. From the [rule book (2003)](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Careers(2003).pdf), (the [1990 version](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Careers(1990).PDF) has the same rules, but they are not written as clearly).

> **Move Your Pawn** - Moving After Rolling: If your pawn is on the main path, move it clockwise by the full count of both dice. If it's on a Career Path, move it toward the end of the path **by the full count of one die**. (page 3)
>
> Before entering the career path, you must meet one of the requirements Listed on the Entrance space (unless you played the Special Opportunity card, which let's you in for free). For example ... (page 5)
>
> **Completing A Career:** When you leave a career path, **continue moving clockwise along the Main path**. ... (page 5)

Comment: Ah that is clear, this is the 1950s version so I can go Plutonium Prospecting in Peru! thanks

Comment: I also though it was a bit funny that on exiting the Uni career you are met with a food bill!